# VB.Net Picturebox paint is too slow when scroll the picturebox on Windows 10

Tags: vb.net

I have a `WinForm` application which has one of the form where I need to add around 5000 controls (labels/shaper) to `PictureBox`. The application is working fine on Windows 7. But recently when I tried it on Windows 10, It is too much slow when we scroll the Picture box and also system is not allowing to do any other operation till paint event is done.

Following is the layout of the form which has `PictureBox` in it:

```
Form -> TableLayoutPanel -> Panel -> PictureBox

If Not MachineHorizontalLanes_Future Is Nothing Then
                If MachineHorizontalLanes_Future.Count > 0 Then
                    If Not canvas_Future Is Nothing Then
                        canvas_Future.Shapes.AddRange(MachineHorizontalLanes_Future)
                        MachineHorizontalLanes_Future = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If Not MachineVerticalLanes_Future Is Nothing Then
                If MachineVerticalLanes_Future.Count > 0 Then
                    If Not canvas_Future Is Nothing Then
                        canvas_Future.Shapes.AddRange(MachineVerticalLanes_Future)
                        MachineVerticalLanes_Future = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If Not pbLotBox_Future Is Nothing Then
                If pbLotBox_Future.Count > 0 Then
                    PBGraphFuture.Controls.AddRange(pbLotBox_Future.Clone)
                    pbLotBox_Future = Nothing
                End If
            End If
```

In Win7 it was working.
In Win10 it is working but its too slow when we scroll the picture box.

Comment: Anytime someone says something like "I need to add 5000 controls to a form" I cringe.  More often than not thats a solid indication that the design is fatally flawed.  You probably need to go back to the drawing board and rethink your approach.

Comment: May/May not be the design issue. Still its working without any issue in Win7 but in Win10 its freezing when I scroll the Picturebox. Rest all fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from **label controls** to **Rectangle Shaper controls** and the paint performance has been increased.